# Download itext generated PDF in html

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, rest

I am trying to download pdf file generated by itext.

In my application, jquery, rest web service is being used.

As of now, i am able to create pdf file at server side but facing issue while sending to html.

I have tried below links with no success.

[iTextSharp generated PDF: How to send the pdf to the client and add a prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505995/itextsharp-generated-pdf-how-to-send-the-pdf-to-the-client-and-add-a-prompt)

[Download pdf file using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax)

When i see in developer tool, i can see below data in response of ajax request.

> Block quote%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x���|E� ...
>
> Block quote

Comment: duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165424/download-file-via-jquery-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating it in memory or creating a file on server. There are number of methods to do this. Either you can [manipulate the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/4361743) and pass in the response. Create a file on server and pass the file url in response and open it in new tab. It depends on which language you are doing.
[Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.pdf"
```